# ECSlidingViewController and testing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, testing, xcode4

I'm using ECSlidingViewController 0.9.0 (https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController). I started with a fresh install with core data, arc & testing enabled, and installed ECSlidingViewController with Cocoapods.

When I run it in test mode, for some reason the slidingViewController method returns null instead of the InitialSlidingViewController.

This is the method defined in ECSlidingViewController.m

```
- (ECSlidingViewController *)slidingViewController
{
  UIViewController *viewController = self.parentViewController;
  while (!(viewController == nil || [viewController isKindOfClass:[ECSlidingViewController class]])) {
    viewController = viewController.parentViewController;
  }

  return (ECSlidingViewController *)viewController;
}
```

In both simulator and test, self.parentViewController returns an InitialSlidingViewController.

But in test mode, [viewController isKindOfClass:[ECSlidingViewController class]] returns false instead of true.

Any idea where I should look next

Comment: Why did you place a bounty on this? It looks like you solved your problem. Is that not the case?

Comment: I found the answer after I placed the bounty, and it seems I can't close it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem wasn't related to ECSlidingViewController.

The answer is here [isKindOfClass: returns false negative in unit test bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755289/iskindofclass-returns-false-negative-in-unit-test-bundle).

I removed the app's source files in the test bundle's compile sources build phase and it works now.