# isKindOfClass Behavior

Tags: objective-c

Can someone explain why isKindOfClass returns different results depending on how the instance was created?

```
@interface BaseClass
...

@interface DerivedClassA : BaseClass
...

DerivedClassA *instance = [[DerivedClassA alloc] init];

[instance isKindOfClass:[BaseClass class]];  // yields YES

Class c = NSClassFromString(@"DerivedClassA");
id instance = [[c alloc] init];

[instance isKindOfClass:[BaseClass class]];  // yields NO
```

Everything else I can glean from the two types in the debugger is identical. I can even compare both results of NSStringFromClass([instance superclass]) and they are equal.

I must be missing something simple.

**Updated Code**

This is the unit test code.

```
LightingUnit *u1 = [[LightingUnit alloc] init];

STAssertTrue([u1 isKindOfClass:[ModelBase class]], @"should be derived from base");

Class uc = NSClassFromString(@"LightingUnit");
id u2 = [[uc alloc] init];

STAssertTrue([u2 isKindOfClass:[ModelBase class]], @"should be derived from base");
```

Here are the class definitions.

```
@interface ModelBase : NSObject

@property (readonly) NSString *__type;

- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;

- (NSMutableDictionary *)dictionary;

@end

@interface LightingUnit : ModelBase

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property NSInteger unitId;

@end
```

**Possible Answer**

When I run this logic outside of the test environment its works without issue. Obviously the only difference is removing the STAssertTrue statements and replacing them with my conditions. In this case they both return YES. I even tried to create a simplified example (no ivars in base or derived) and it fails in test but works in standard runtime.

Any ideas why this might only be an issue when testing? Is my test target missing something?

**Solved**

I had included the .m files in the testing targets compile sources. Once removed this started behaving as expected. Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364074/iskindofclass-and-nsstringfromclass-disagree-about-uiapplicationdelegate) for helping me resolve this.

Comment: just tried, get two YES. try print the class of `instance`

Comment: Is that supposed to be `BaseClass : NSObject`? The answer to that question will change the answer to your question.

Comment: You need to paste your real code. Your sample code works just fine, as long as I make `BaseClass` a subclass of `NSObject` (it doesn't even compile otherwise).

Comment: @xlc0212 try running as unit test.

Answer (score 2):

I added your code in a test app of mine. I had to change the name of the two `instance` variables, afterwards the compiler gave me a warning ("Class method '+alloc' not found"), and the program crashed when I ran it.

I then changed this line:

```
@interface BaseClass : NSObject
```

i.e. I derived `BaseClass` from `NSObject`. No more compiler warning and the code runs as expected, i.e. the second `isKindOfClass` returns YES.

I don't know if the missing `NSObject` is what causes your problem. If it's not then someone else has to step in. If it is, I wonder how you were able to run your code at all.

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not `BaseClass` inherits from `NSObject` will change the outcome of this code. Here are the two possibilities:

---

```
@interface BaseClass
```

If you have defined `BaseClass` *without* inheriting from `NSObject`, then quite frankly I'm surprised the compiler let you get away with setting up your `instance` variable.
Unless you defined your own `+alloc` and `-init` methods on `BaseClass` (which is possible), then the first line of your test won't work at all. If you did define an appropriate `+alloc` and `-init` method, you'll still run into trouble with `-isKindOfClass:` as you'll need to define that yourself as well.
So basically this won't work, let's look at the next option...

---

```
@interface BaseClass : NSObject
```

The first line of your test (creating `instance`) should work fine.

`[instance isKindOfClass:[BaseClass class]]` returns the appropriate value, `YES`.

Your `class c` initialisation should work correctly.

I suspect there is something omitted here because the final line should return `YES` with the code you posted (assuming `BaseClass` inherits from `NSObject`)... The final line should return `YES`. I suspect what may have happened is `instance` has somehow wound up containing `nil` through incorrect initialisation/typo/etc. In this case, sending it a message will just return `nil`, and thus sending `-isKindOfClass` will yield `NO`.